# Чем интернет-мем отличается от идиомы?

Tags: общие-вопросы, классификация

*Интернет-мемы* - сравнительно новое явление в языке. Это достаточно устойчивые словосочетания или даже просто некоторые идеи, образы, не обязательно выраженные в словах.

Например: словосочетание «**британские ученые доказали**» употребляется сейчас в качестве ироничного указания на бессмысленность и низкое качество приводимых аргументов и фактов.

Далее, на форумах часто используется, например, выражение **100500** ("СтоПятьсот", "СтоПицот") в значении: "много", "чёрт-знает-сколько". Из этого примера уже видно одно отличие *мема* от обычного фразеологизма - он может быть выражен не только словами, но и цифрами.

Существует ли какой-то научный аналог понятия *мем*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мем - это на самом деле явление гораздо общее. Любая идея является мемом. Очень хорошее определение дано в [википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BC): "единица передачи культурной информации, распространяемая от одного человека к другому посредством имитации, научения и др". Т.е. любое слово, любая устойчивое словосочетание в принципе является мемом. Сам термин мем достаточно научен. Он появился как аналог термина ген в генетике. И на самом деле между ними действительно есть достаточно большое сходство. Мемы появляются, развиваются, живут и исчезают. Иногда сами по себе, иногда будучи вытеснены более удачными или свежими.

Мем отличается от просто какой-либо фразы. Например, идея о Боге (всевышнем) - тоже является мемом. Поэтому мем - это не просто какое-то слово, а само слово как форма того, какой смысл мы в него вкладываем.

Answer (score 9):

Понятие "мем" ввёл в обиход британский учёный (без кавычек) Ричард Докинз. Означает оно минимальную единицу памяти, которую возможно передать. Сюда входят не только слова, но и действия (ношение определённого типа одежды, способ завязывания шнурков), философские понятия (Бог, совесть), жесты.

Говорить о грамотности или неграмотности конкретно интернет-мемов, также бессмысленно как обсуждать грамотность или безграмотность какого-нибудь жаргона или диалекта. У языка общения в Интернете уже появились свои правила, помогающие лучше понять собеседника.

Comment: Другими  словами  -  это  знак.  Приведите  пример,  пожалуйста,  когда  философские  понятия ( бог,  мораль  и  т.п. ) выступают  в  качестве  мемов.  К  примеру  Бог ( с  большой  буквы ) - это  мем ?

Comment: Бог с большой буквы - это безусловно мем. Мем по своей сути - это любой объект нематериального мира, который передаётся от человека к человеку, каким угодно путём. Главная особенность мема -способность к воспроизведению. с большой буквы начал писать один - подхватили и понеслось.
Бог как понятие - вообще довольно древний мем, никто о нём ничего не знает, но используют и передают своё понимание другим. Из множества мемов создаются мемплексы, которые мы привыкли называть культурой и религией.

Comment: У вас более чёткий ответ (и комментарии) в целом, но собс. определение мне кажется убедительней такое: "единица передачи культурной информации...". Поэтому вам - плюс, а ответ выбираю @gecube.

Answer (score 4):

Интернет-язык существует, хотим мы того или нет, считаем ли мы это верхом безграмотности или просто игрой в безграмотность. И с этим надо смириться. Никакой тотальной безграмотностью мемы не грозят. Дремуче безграмотные интернетом, как правило, не пользуются.  Я знаю немало людей не самого низкого интеллекта, не умеющих правильно расставить знаки препинания и допускающих порой довольно грубые орфографические ошибки. И, поверьте, изгоями они не становятся.
 Не стоит, право, паниковать из-за того, что люди общаются на сленге и прекрасно понимают друг друга.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что мем — это явление, касающееся ТОЛЬКО интернета. Причем, некоторые мемы вслух просто даже и не произнесешь, вроде общеизвестного "апстену". Просто, потому что в разговорной речи потеряется особенность написания. Словом, мем годится только для речи письменной, просторечной, для интернет-общения.
Идиома же гораздо более литературна, ее можно употребить как в устной речи, так и в письменной.

Comment: Бывают, однако, мемы-пиктограммы. Например, facepalm (рука-лицо), обозначающий что-то вроде "ну ё-моё!..".

Некоторые исследователи ("британские учёные" :-)) считают мемом пресловутую *мелодию* Jingle Bells.

То есть это некий образ, некая идея, бодро шагающая по головам громадного числа людей. А выражена она, получается, может быть не только словами (и не только буквами).

Comment: Виртуальные сетевые образы, в том числе и наиболее яркие в плане передачи эмоций смайлики, имеют право на свою нишу. Общение в интернете без всего этого добра никак обойтись не может и не хочет. А сколько мемов существует в религиозной сфере или любой профессиональной, ведь не сосчитать... Мем гаишника : "Нарушаем?")))

Comment: Угу. И "предъявите деньги")))) Я согласна, что смайлики имеют право на существование, включая тот же "фэйспалм", ибо как еще реагировать на вопросы после просмотра имериканской "Анны Карениной": "Я еще хочу почитать  Анну Каренину. Что она еще написала?")))))
Да и словечки типа "стопицот", если они употреблены грамотным человеком, который может позволить себе подобную вольность, могут присутствовать в разговорной речи, но только с ироничным оттенком. Например, некоторых графоманом ну никак "авторами" не назовешь. Только "аффтарами")))

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, всё это происки безграмотных людей. Правил они не знают, поэтому говорят (а хуже того - ещё и пишут) как умеют. И всё это норовит войти в норму с лёгкой руки тех, кто поддерживает подобные явления.

Comment: Некоторые исследователи считают мемами такие выражения, как "слава Герострата" и "синдром вахтёра". Так что это не обязательно от безграмотности.

Answer (score 1):

"Дремуче безграмотные Интернетом, как правило, не пользуются"- это что, шутка такая? Может, мы с вами на разных планетах живем и разными Интернетами пользуемся?

Comment: А вы себя или меня к дремуче безграмотным отнесли?

Answer (score 0):

Интересный вопрос и интересные ответы! Из всего вышесказанного хочется сделать какой-то небольшой вывод. Как я поняла, мем - единица информации (можно сравнить с единицей памяти компьютера), и не важно, какая именно информация заложена (грамотно или неграмотно изложенная). То есть его можно поставить в один ряд с единицами языка, такими как фонема, графема, морфема, слово, лексема, словосочетание, предложение, текст. По сути, любая лексема (но не любое слово) является мемом. Что касается прочих языковых единиц, надо подумать. Впрочем, мем наверняка может быть представлен и фонемой, и графемой, и т. д., главное, чтобы была идея, передаваемая от человека к человеку. Нет, идеи или особого смысла даже может и не быть, а просто какой-то повторяемый "психокод", вызывающий какие-то эмоции. Вообще любопытное явление. [Мем](http://kaschepuzia.kaschenko.ru/index.php/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BC).

P.S. Все-таки надо разграничить "мем" в широком смысле слова и интернет-мем как особое явление.

Comment: Неправильно говорить, что мем - единица информации. Единица информации - бит. А мем - это **знак**. Он обязательно имеет план выражения и план содержания (в отличие, например, от *фонемы*).

---------------

Значение у мема может быть не любое, а обязательно связанное с человеческой культурой. Структура значения мема, выраженного словами, всегда достаточно жёсткая - это фигура речи "аллюзия", мем всегда отсылает к чему-то известному, намекает на что-то, что получатель информации должен был знать раньше.

Comment: А то что "мем - единица передачи культурной информации" - тоже неправильно? "Мем" - очевидно, сокращено от "мемори". Единицы информации бывают разные. В компьютерной системе - биты. В языковой - единицы языка. В меметике (http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) - мемы. Вы спросили о научном аналоге понятия мем. Так какую именно науку Вы имели ввиду? По-моему, еще более неправильно и неточно говорить, что мем - это знак. Знак какой - графический, мимический, знак жеста, звуковой?.. Фонема - это тоже знак (графическое обозначение звука).

Comment: Именно единица **культурной** информации (не какой угодно). При этом обязательно имеющая план выражения. Я имел в виду какую-нибудь науку, чьим предметом могли бы быть мемы, то есть знаки. Например, лингвистику. Или семиотику.

Comment: Думаю, изучением мемов должна заниматься именно меметика. Боюсь, что с точки зрения лингвистики или семиотики исследование мемов окажется ограниченным. Хотя, может, когда-то и появится новый раздел лингвистики "интернет-лингвистика", где упомянут и о мемах.

Comment: Немного о меметике:   
*Концепции меметики, в частности, позволяют описывать в терминах генетики размножение, распространение, отбор, мутации и рекомбинации, а также и смерть мемов - этих элементарных единиц, квантов культуры. Такими информационными квантами – мемами, могут выступать сформулированные идеи, лозунги, религиозные догмы, мода на тот или иной стереотип поведения, музыкальные мотивы, литературные клише и обороты используемые авторами печатных работ и т.д.*   
[Источник] [1]
[1]: http://www.biometrica.tomsk.ru/lis/index18.htm

Comment: @inna, спасибо за интересную ссылку.

Answer (score 0):

Мем отличается от идиомы прежде всего тем, что он входит в мемплексы. Нет вхождения в мемплекс, нет мема.
То, что часто называют интернет-мемами, почти всегда - карикатуры, комиксы, квази-олигофренизмы, слова-паразиты и выражения-паразиты.
Марк Из пишет "Из множества мемов создаются мемплексы, которые мы привыкли называть культурой и религией". Мемом является слово/понятие "культура", а мемплексом - понятийный аппарат культурологии.
[Мемплексом](http://blagaved.ru/index.php/Мемплекс) является не религия, а набор богословских тропов. Точно также мемплексами являются тезаурусы гуманитарных наук.